# How to check for an empty php area?

Tags: php

I’m trying to run a simple PHP script that puts a banner in the header position on a Wordpress website if there isn’t already one there. How do I construct an `if` statement that says “if the bannerAd position is blank, put template-header in its place”? The code shown below compiles fine but doesn’t display.

```
  <?php if (bannerAd==('')) bannerAd('template-header'); ?>
```

This piece of code is an example of a long list of PHP commands that puts custom banners on the appropriate pages (and this works):

```
<?php if ((get_post_meta("$post->ID", '_as_roomname', true)=='Paddy Power Sportsbook'))  bannerad('paddy-power-sports'); ?>
<?php if ((get_post_meta("$post->ID", '_as_roomname', true)=='SkyBet'))  bannerad('skybet'); ?>
<?php if ((get_post_meta("$post->ID", '_as_roomname', true)=='William Hill Sportsbook'))  bannerad('william-hill-sports'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what `bannerAd` exactly is, but you need to somehow store the data, if there is already something, whether by checking if it is already set or if it is [empty](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

```
if(empty($bannerAd))
    $bannerAd = 'template-header';
```

I assume that `$bannerAd` is a variable.

Comment: Hmm.. I thought that would work but it doesn't. Instead, the template-header appears on all pages as well as pages that already have one.